# CakePHP 3 - Model - Accessing data from third layer of array

Tags: cakephp-3.0

CakePHP 3

**My Model**

Users has Many Badges

Titles has Many Badges

Badges belongs to Titles

Badges belongs to Users

In my Users View, I want to access the value of Titles but I don't know how.

```
**Users Controller**

public function view($id = null)
{
  $this->viewBuilder()->layout('admin');
  TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Badges', 'Projects', 'Reports', 'Rewards']
    ]);
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}





    UsersTable.php
    $this->hasMany('Badges', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);

    TitleTable.php
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Titles', [
        'foreignKey' => 'title_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);


    BadgesTable.php
    $this->hasMany('Badges', [
        'foreignKey' => 'title_id'
    ]);


 App\Model\Entity\User Object
(
   [id] => 1
[firstname] => Jl
[lastname] => C
[email] => m
[username] => admin
[password] => 
[profile_pic] => /img/noimage.jpg
[report_count] => 0
[role] => admin
[reputation] => 999999
[account_status] => Active
[confirmation] => 1
[site_name] => C
[site_email] => mi
[created] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
    (
        [time] => 2017-02-27T13:46:51+08:00
        [timezone] => Asia/Manila
        [fixedNowTime] => 
    )

[modified] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
    (
        [time] => 2017-03-01T10:37:50+08:00
        [timezone] => Asia/Manila
        [fixedNowTime] => 
    )

[badges] => Array
    (
        [0] => App\Model\Entity\Badge Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [title_id] => 11
                [created] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
                    (
                        [time] => 2017-02-28T15:16:08+08:00
                        [timezone] => Asia/Manila
                        [fixedNowTime] => 
                    )

                [modified] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
                    (
                        [time] => 2017-02-28T15:16:08+08:00
                        [timezone] => Asia/Manila
                        [fixedNowTime] => 
                    )

                [[new]] => 
                [[accessible]] => Array
                    (
                        [*] => 1
                    )

                [[dirty]] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [[original]] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [[virtual]] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [[errors]] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [[invalid]] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [[repository]] => Badges
            )
    )

[[new]] => 
[[accessible]] => Array
    (
        [*] => 1
    )

[[repository]] => Users
```

)

What I want is to get the data from title table (i.e name)

```
    [badges] => Array
         (
        [0] => App\Model\Entity\Badge Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [title_id] => 11
                [created] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `contain`, you can use `'Model.Model'` to get further related data like so :

```
$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Badges.Titles', 'Projects', 'Reports', 'Rewards']
]);
```

Comment: It works! Wonderful! Now, how can I fetch the data in my view?

Comment: This is my code for Users view.
<?php foreach($user->badges as $badges): ?>
 <li><?php echo $this->Html->link($badges->name, ['controller' => 'Badges', 'action' => 'view', $badges->id]);?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: Have you figured it out yet? You can debug `$user` in the view, then use `foreach` or I need to see your debug for further help.

Comment: Yes Yes Yes!. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad to help :)